# Correct structure and query for Realtime Firebase Database

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I structure my database in Firebase for search for recipes? Each recipe have some ingridients. I need to search for recipes. If the query contains several matching ingredients, I need to output a recipe containing a matching value.

It is my strucuture of database now :

```
{
  "Recepts" : [ {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Carrot", "Sugar" ],
    "Name" : "Carrot Salad"
  }, {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Orange", "Milk" ],
    "Name" : "Orange Milk"
  } ]
}
```

If this is correct, how can I do a query for my database?

Answer (score 0):

[It is a best practice](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push) to avoid using array and save list of data as map instead.

To search for recipes having an ingredient, [you could use `orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key) together with `equalTo` the ingredient you are looking for.

The data structure would be

```
{
    "Recipes" : {
        "CarrotSalad": {
            "Ingredients" : {
                "Carrot": true,
                "Sugar": true
            },
            "Name" : "Carrot Salad"
        }, 
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not difficult for you, can you give an example of such a query?

Comment: @ВладЮлин I don't know the language you're using, anyway following the second link in my post you can see an official example in several languages. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you found is useful, please, it is very important for stackoverflow to keep working as it should